# How to add vue-style-loader dependency in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

In my project, I created a new file header.vue in src/components/header/. The code is

```
<template>
  <div class="header">
    I am header!!
  </div>
</template>
<script type="text/ecmascript-6">
  export default({})
</script>
<style lang="stylus" rel="stylesheet/stylus">
</style>
```

I want to use it in App.vue, Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <header></header>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
   import header from './components/header/header.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      header: header
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
#app {
 .....
}
```

But i have got error in console:

```
This dependency was not found:

* !!vue-style-loader!css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!../../../node_modules/vue- 
 loader/lib/style-compiler/index?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v- 
 12835cef","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!stylus-loader? 
 {"sourceMap":true}!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector? 
 type=styles&index=0!./header.vue in ./src/components/header/header.vue
```

I had found that ""css-loader": "^0.28.0"," is in package.jsaon already, So I added

```
"stylus-loader": "^2.1.1",
```

into package.json. and restarted "npm run dev"

But unlucky, it doesn't work, it failed again. Who can help me ?

Comment: did you add the rule for stylus in your webpack config?

Comment: Did you generate the vue project using vue-cli? If yes the which version of vue-cli?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna, yes, I used  "npm install -g vue-cli" and "vue init webpack sell".  The version of vue is 2.9.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1:** Add `stylus-loader` as a dev dependency by executing the following command

```
npm install stylus stylus-loader --save-dev
```

**2:** Add the stylus rule to the webpack config

Locate the `webpack.base.conf.js` in the build folder and add the following rule

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.styl$/,
      loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'stylus-loader']
    }
  ]
}
```